# Firestore determine data field value performance in between a date range and combine it with others

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want the following data result: Give me all **films** where **genre** is equal to a given genre, compare the **`watchcount`** value from all films from last 30 days and show me the most watched films in this period `desc`.

This is a quite advanced request for me and I still didn't find a smart solution after research. I would love to see a solution how to get that approach done within firestore.

I have all the films in its own collection. If a client does watch the film, I'm incrementing a field value of the film called `totalWatchCount`.

I want to show most watched films from 30 days for example, but there is no smart data structure coming in my mind how to get the performance inside this period. I can only receive the top watched films since creationdate for example.

I have to compare all the films and determine the performance in between the given period and filter out these results, but I have no idea how the structure has to look like.

this is how I receive the data right now:

```
snapshot = await db
    .collection('films')
    .where('genre', arrayContainsAny: userGenres)
    .where('dateFilter.year', isEqualTo: '21')
    .where('dateFilter.month', isEqualTo: 'MAR')
    .where('dateFilter.week', isEqualTo: '2')
    .orderBy('totalWatchCount', descending: true)
    .limit(5)
    .get()
    .catchError((error) => print(error));

    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      Film film = Film.fromJson(document.data());
      _res.add(film);
    });
  }
```

**I'm not able to compare all films watchCount in between a given Period, for example 30 days, because I only have access to the total count but not in between and cant compare it to others.**

How can we make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array that contains the day-number as key and the viewcount as value or vice versa.

Everytime you write a view-event you check if the current date already exists in the array, if so you overwrite it.

You could do this as day # of the month. Start at 1 and end at 29,30,31 etc.

Example:

```
[ 01-04: 100, 02-04: 50, 03-04: 120 ]
```

So if I add another viewer-event to the db I would:

- check if day number '1' exists for April, create if not.
- if the current date is 01-05 I would overwrite this entry with 01-04: 1.
- if the current date is 01-04, which it is, we just increment the 100 by 1 to 101.

To make it easier to parse you could just add the timestamp as key.

This way you can use a .where to measure the biggest gaps between days in the last month.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. great idea! How would I setup the function as we are going to have a lot of writes? Would you do it with a distributed counter feature since we have a write limit? Would we do the fieldvalue.increment and use a batch (or maybe a transaction)? would you do it as cloud function for safety reasons? Greetings

Comment: Another thing: I also need to messure the performance in a week but compare it to other films. I need to now which of the films are watched most in week 2 of april for example

Comment: I believe firebase has a .sum function. You could also just write a cloud function to check this every day instead of every request.